# Prove that exponential sweep sine decay 6 dB per octave

Tags: audio, impulse-response, measurement

[Exponential sweep sine](https://www.melaudia.net/zdoc/sweepSine.PDF) (ESS) is a good excitation signal to measure the impulse response of an acoustic system, such as loudspeaker - room - microphone system. An ESS has the form of

$$
x(t) = \sin\Big[\frac{2\pi f_1 T}{R} (e^{tR/T} - 1) \Big]
$$
where $t$ is the time variable in second, $T$ is the duration of the sine sweep, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the start and final frequency in Hz, respectively, and $R=\ln(f_2/f_1)$ is the exponential sweep rate.

The signal has a constant magnitude over time, and the magnitude spectrum shows a decay, of 6 dB per octave to be precise. This magnitude decay must be compensated when the impulse response is calculated with the deconvolution procedure.

In this [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69784/fourier-transform-of-an-exponential-sine-sweep) Matt states that ESS doesn't have a close form Fourier transform. So my question is that is it possible to prove this 6 dB per octave decay. In this case we only need the magnitude of the Fourier transform of ESS.

Related question: [Calculating the inverse filter for the (exponential) sine sweep Method](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41696/calculating-the-inverse-filter-for-the-exponential-sine-sweep-method/41700#41700)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [JAES paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02504321/document) gives a close form of the Fourier transform of the synchronized swept-sine (SSS) signal which has the same form as the ESS

$$
x(t) = \sin \big\{2\pi f_1L \big[\exp(t/L) -1 \big]\big\}
$$
where
$$
L = \frac{1}{f_1} \mathrm{round}\left[\frac{\hat{T}f_1}{\ln(f_2/f_1)}\right]
$$
and $\hat{T}$ is the approximate time length of $x(t)$.

The authors derive the Fourier transform of the analytic signal of the SSS:
$$
z(t) = \exp\Big\{j2\pi f_1L \big[\exp(t/L) -1\big]\Big\}
$$
and
$$
Z(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty z(t) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt
$$

After a long derivation, we have the final result

$$
Z(f) = \exp\left[ j2\pi fL\left( 1-\ln\frac{f}{f_1} \right) \right] \times \sqrt{\frac{L}{f}} \exp(j\frac{\pi}{4})
$$

The magnitude of $Z(f)$ is inversely proportional to $\sqrt{f}$, i. e. the Fourier spectrum falls down by 3 dB/octave, and the power spectrum decreases by 6 dB/octave.

Comment: BTW, compared with ESS, SSS is a better way to measure the phase of a nonlinear system.

Comment: this is really cool.  the paper done **completely** in continuous-time mathematics.  until the Appendix A.2, where there is code, all of the paper was continuous math.  no samples.  no $x[n]$. $$ $$ wow.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yeah, math is beautiful!